# PDE solution, how to find the initial condition in three variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working with a simple PDE given below.

$$u_x+u_y+2u_z=0$$

with I.C. given as $u(x,0,z)=x+z$. I managed to find the solution $u$ by using the method of characteristics so the solution is
$$u(x,y,z)=F(y-x,z-2x)$$

Here comes the question. How can I use my I.C. on the solution I found? I know how to do it if the PDE is in two variables, but not in three.

Using Maple I obtain
$$u(x,y,z)=x-3y+z$$
but I would like to learn to do it by hand. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found the general solution :
$$u(x,y,z)=F(X,Y)\quad\text{with}\quad\begin{cases}X=y-x\\Y=z-2x\end{cases}$$
Condition :
$$u(x,0,z)=x+z=F(X,Y)\quad\text{with}\quad\begin{cases}X=-x\\Y=z-2x\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}x=-X\\z=Y+2(-X)=Y-2X\end{cases}$$
$$F(X,Y)=x+z=(-X)+(Y-2X)=Y-3X$$
Now the function $F$ is known :
$$F(X,Y)=Y-3X$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=y-x$ and $Y=z-2x$ .

$$u(x,y,z)=Y-3X=(z-2x)-3(y-x)$$
$$u(x,y,z)=x-3y+z$$

Comment: This makes sence for me, I didn't know it was so simple!